# Convert thousands of small JSON files from s3 to one big CSV in lambda

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to merge multiple small JSON files (about 500,000 files of 400-500 byte size and are no longer susceptible to change) into one big CSV file, using AWS Lambda. I have a job that works something like this:

1. Use the s3.listobjects() to fetch keys
2. Use s3.getObject() to fetch each JSON file (is there a better way to do this?)
3. Create a CSV file in-memory (what's the best way to do this in nodejs?)
4. Upload that file in S3

I'd love to know if there's a better way to go about doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Are these files changing and/or are new files being added?  If this is a one off then there is little point using an event driven environment like Lambda - a modest EC2, spun up to do what you need would be simpler.  And it's not clear how long it will take to list and read 500K files too.

Comment: @stdunbar files are not susceptible to change and new files are not added at the time of the job run. it is kind of a piece of the lambda workflow that I have so I am trying to keep all the functions in lambda. easier to maintain. I was wondering if the writeStream in nodejs has any merit

Comment: If this data is static then can't this be done one time via Lambda, EC2, or whatever and then never done again?

Comment: @stdunbar that's the idea, to do it once only for a given folder. And I am trying to find a way to automate it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **Amazon Athena**.

It allows you to run SQL commands across multiple data files simultaneously ([including JSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-JSON.html)) and can create output files by [Creating a Table from Query Results (CTAS) - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I haven't used Athena before, so I was wondering if there's a way I can trigger generation of the csv from a subset of s3 files in athena from lambda

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trigger", but an AWS Lambda function can certainly make an API call to run a query in Amazon Athena. I would suggest using the Amazon Athena management console first to create and debug the query, then you could automate its execution with a Lambda function.